# Struggling with Google Maps geocoding API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, twitter, google-maps-api-3

I am currently working on an application that periodically (every 30 secs) grabs two tweets within the UK from two specified football teams using the json format.  Within the json file I can access the location of each tweet which is currently textual (manchester, bristol etc).

What I need to do is somehow geocode the locations and use the lat,lng co-ords to plot the tweet data onto multiple (2) infowindows.  I've had a crack at using the geocode API but have had no luck yet. Currently I'm trying to just output the co-ords into a test div to see if it works, but it isn't.

My general code is below if that helps, any advice or help regarding this would be grrreat!
(currently I am also just outputting the twitter data into placeholder divs for the  meantime)

```
//create urls for grabbing both teams tweets in the UK area
var url1="http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=
%23"+team1+"&callback=?&geocode=53.779292%2C-1.579413%2C350mi";
var url2="http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=
%23"+team2+"&callback=?&geocode=53.779292%2C-1.579413%2C350mi";

function team1tweets()
{
           $.getJSON(
           url1,function(results){ // get the tweets
           var res1 = results.results[0].text;
           var user1name = results.results[0].from_user;
           var user1Location = results.results[0].location;

           // get the first tweet in the response and place it inside the div
           $("#last-tweet1").html(res1 + "<p>from: " + user1name + " (" +
user1Location + ")</p><p>");
           }
           );

           //convert location into longitude and latitude
           var convertLocUrl1 = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/
json?address=" + userLocation1 + "&sensor=false&region=uk";
           convertLocUrl1,function(locResult){
           var lat1 = locResult.results[0].geometry.location.lat();
           var lng1 = locResult.results[0].geometry.location.lng();
           $("#testDiv").html("latitude:" + lat1 + "<p>longitude:" + lng1 + "</
p>");
           }

}

function team2tweets()
{
           $.getJSON(
           url2,function(results){ // get the tweets
           var res2 = results.results[0].text;
           var user2name = results.results[0].from_user;
           var user2Location = results.results[0].location;
           $("#last-tweet2").html(res2 + "<p>from: " + user2name + " (" +
user2Location + ")</p>"); // get the first tweet in the response and
place it inside the div
           });

//convert location into longitude and latitude
           var convertLocUrl2 = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/
json?address=" + userLocation2 + "&sensor=false&region=uk";
           convertLocUrl2,function(locResult){
           var lat2 = locResult.results[0].geometry.location.lat();
           var lng2 = locResult.results[0].geometry.location.lng();
           $("#testDiv2").html("latitude:" + lat2 + "<p>longitude:" + lng2 + "</
p>");
           }
}

team1tweets();
team2tweets();

setInterval(checkStream1,20000);
setInterval(checkStream2,20000);


function checkStream1()
{
           team1tweets();
}

function checkStream2()
{
           team2tweets();
}
});
</script>
```

UPDATE: new code, using Google Maps API v3

```
 <HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Tweet Ball</TITLE>
<LINK REL="Stylesheet" href="tweetBallStyles.css"></LINK>
<script src="https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

<!--GRABBING AND DISPLAYING TWEETS-->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
var team1, team2; 
//get team hashtag info
team1 = '<?php echo $_GET["team1"]; ?>'; 
team2 = '<?php echo $_GET["team2"]; ?>'; 

 //create urls for grabbing both teams tweets in the UK area
var url1="http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23"+team1+"&callback=?&geocode=53.779292%2C-1.579413%2C350mi";
var url2="http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23"+team2+"&callback=?&geocode=53.779292%2C-1.579413%2C350mi";
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function team1tweets() {
$.getJSON(
url1, function(results) { // get the tweets
    var res1 = results.results[0].text;
    var user1name = results.results[0].from_user;
    var user1Location = results.results[0].location;

    // get the first tweet in the response and place it inside the div
    $("#last-tweet1").html(res1 + "<p>from: " + user1name + " (" + user1Location + ")</p><p>");
    //convert location into longitude and latitude
    geocoder.geocode({
        address: user1Location 
        }, function(locResult) {
            console.log(locResult);
            var lat1 = locResult[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var lng1 = locResult[0].geometry.location.lng();
            $("#testDiv").html("latitude:" + lat1 + "<p>longitude:" + lng1 + "</p>");
    });
});
}


function team2tweets() {
$.getJSON(
url2, function(results) { // get the tweets
    var res2 = results.results[0].text;
    var user2name = results.results[0].from_user;
    var user2Location = results.results[0].location;

    // get the first tweet in the response and place it inside the div
    $("#last-tweet2").html(res2 + "<p>from: " + user2name + " (" + user2Location + ")</p><p>");
    //convert location into longitude and latitude
    geocoder.geocode({
        address: user2Location 
        }, function(locResult) {
            console.log(locResult);
            var lat2 = locResult[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var lng2 = locResult[0].geometry.location.lng();
            $("#testDiv2").html("latitude:" + lat2 + "<p>longitude:" + lng2 + "</p>");
    });
});
}


team1tweets();
team2tweets();

//setInterval(checkStream1, 10000);
//setInterval(checkStream2, 10000);

function checkStream1() {
team1tweets();
}

function checkStream2() {
team2tweets();
}})
</script>

</HEAD>


<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header"></div><!--end of header div-->

<div id="mainContent">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php">return to team select</li>
</ul>

<div id="testDiv"></div>
<div id="testDiv2"></div>

<div id="map_canvas"></div>

<div id="last-tweet1-container">
<div id="last-tweet1">
</div>
</div>

<div id="last-tweet2-container">
<div id="last-tweet2">
</div>
</div>



<div id="footer">
</div>
</div><!--end of mainContent div--> 
</div><!--end of container div-->
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: what do you get when you do `console.log(lat1 + ' ' + lng1)` , and what is team1 and team2?

Comment: I've tried console.log but nothing is appearing in Firebug.  team1 and team2 are variables containing twitter hashtags (eg, afc)

Comment: @Jono can you give me dummy data for thoese two fields?

Comment: a typical example would be: manchester.

Comment: I think perhaps the conversion (geocoding) function cannot see the user1Location variable that it is using. But I can't see a way around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [JSFiddle Demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/ETyZL/) using Google Map V3 API's Geocode to get the lat and lng of your locations:

I am able to modify your code to the following without error.  Basically, you have to call the Google Map Geocode within your first getJSON, because user1Location is retrived async and thus undefined when accessed outside of your twitter json callback.  AFAIK, [Google Geocode VIA HTTP does not allow JSONP](https://groups.google.com/forum/?lnk=gst&q=callback#!topic/google-maps-api/MC3olbEkD_U), and thus, retriving HTTP through JavaScript VIA Ajax is a violation of cross-domain policy.  Another alternative is to use the Google Map API V3's Geocoding or you can use server side to retrive the HTTP JSON.

```
function team1tweets() {
    $.getJSON(
    url1, function(results) { // get the tweets
        var res1 = results.results[0].text;
        var user1name = results.results[0].from_user;
        var user1Location = results.results[0].location;

        // get the first tweet in the response and place it inside the div
        $("#last-tweet1").html(res1 + "<p>from: " + user1name + " (" + user1Location + ")</p><p>");
        //convert location into longitude and latitude
        var convertLocUrl1 = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + user1Location + "&sensor=false&region=uk";
        $.getJSON(convertLocUrl1,function(locResult) {
                var lat1 = locResult.results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var lng1 = locResult.results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                $("#testDiv").html("latitude:" + lat1 + "<p>longitude:" + lng1 + "</p>");
        });
    });
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Here is the Google Map API V3 way of getting LatLng of the locations you wish.  Apply similar code to your `team2tweets()`.  I basically replace your $.getJSON with google.map.Geocode:

```
function team1tweets() {
    $.getJSON(
    url1, function(results) { // get the tweets
        var res1 = results.results[0].text;
        var user1name = results.results[0].from_user;
        var user1Location = results.results[0].location;

        // get the first tweet in the response and place it inside the div
        $("#last-tweet1").html(res1 + "<p>from: " + user1name + " (" + user1Location + ")</p><p>");
        //convert location into longitude and latitude
        geocoder.geocode({
            address: user1Location 
            }, function(locResult) {
                console.log(locResult);
                var lat1 = locResult[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var lng1 = locResult[0].geometry.location.lng();
                $("#testDiv").html("latitude:" + lat1 + "<p>longitude:" + lng1 + "</p>");
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at that for me! I thought I was using the Google Map API V3 Geocoding.  How is that different to what I'm doing?  I've trawled thorugh their documentation but can't find anything specific to what I need.

Comment: @Jono you were using google map geocode through HTTP similar to what you were doing with twitter.  Google doesn't allow JSONP on their Geocode HTTP, and thus, you have issue with it through client side.  However, if you use google map javascript api then the Geocode will work.  It all have to do with cross-domain when using JSONP

Comment: Thanks so much, kji112.  I'll give all this a try now.  I've literally spent all day on this so far so you've really helped me out.

Comment: @kjy112, sorry to be a pain. I have implemented your code and it is outputting the lat and lng nicely.  However, the page does not seem to be updating (in accordance with the setInterval function).  Any ideas why that may be?

Comment: @Jono are you getting this `ÜT: 50.930579,-1.381443` as your location from twitter?  Sometimes, twitter JSON would output actual latlng instead of address.  So, basically you'll have to check to see if twitter returns `ÜT: 50.930579,-1.381443` then parse latlng out else use Geocode

Comment: @kjy112, I get something like that occasionally (as some people have their location set differently) but most people seem to have textual locations. I plan to integrate some kind of 'if statement' later to deal with this.  My current problem is that the setInterval update doesn't seem to be working anymore - even when the locations are textual.

Comment: @kjy112, I have updated the original question with my entire php file.  So, should I not use $getJson at all if I am using google maps API?

Comment: Joni please create another question. Its kind of hard to see. Ill help you in few hours

Comment: @kjy112, ah sorry, its because 'setInterval' was commented out - just to confirm, is it ok if I use the setInterval with the Google Maps v3 geocoding?